# teclado en linea telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram

tengo un teclado que me llama 4 botones que a su ves llaman otros botones, necesito que uno de estos botones al llamar a los callbackdata corran o ejecuten una funcion y de acuerdo a esta envie mensaje.

```
//TECLADO
if($text == "teclado"){
$keyboard = [
    ["Linea1", "Linea2"],
    ["Linea3", "Linea4"],
];
    $kiniteam->keyboard($keyboard, "Bienvenido al bot para aprender el PhP!", $cid);  
}

if($text == "Linea1"){
    $but = array(array(array("text" => "Boton 1", "url" => "www.google.com"),),);
    $kiniteam->inlineKeyboard($but, $cid, "Haga clic en este2 botón para ir a google!");
}

if($text == "Linea2"){
    $but = array(array(array("text" => "Boton 1", "url" => "www.google.com"),array("text" => "Bottone 2", "url" => "www.facebook.it"),),);
    $kiniteam->inlineKeyboard($but, $cid, "Haga clic en uno de estos dos botones \npara ir a google o facebook!");
}
//BOTON
if($text == "Linea3"){
    $but[] = array(array("text" => "Boton 1", "url" => "www.google.com"),);
    $but[] = array(array("text" => "Boton 2", "url" => "www.facebook.it"),);
    $but[] = array(array("text" => "Boton 3", "callback_data" => "liga2"),);
    $kiniteam->inlineKeyboard($but, $cid, "Haga clic en uno de estos dos botones \npara ir a google o facebook!");
}

if($text == "Linea4"){
    $but = array(array(array("text" => "Boton 1", "callback_data" => "liga1"),),);
    $kiniteam->inlineKeyboard($but, $cid, "Haga clic en el botón!");
}

//CALLBACK DATA _ ACA NECESITO FUNCION
if(callback($update)){

if($cbdata == "liga1"){
    $kiniteam->send($cbid, "Has hecho clic en el botón 1");
    }

    if($cbdata == "liga2"){

    $kiniteam->send($cbid, "cccccxccx");
    }
}
```

Comment: la verdad asi encontre parte en la web y me funciona, la verdad no se como andarle la funcion en el callbackdata alguna idea}

Comment: CALLBACK DATA lo tienes que hacer con ajax específicamente javascript.
por que php es lenguage en servidor y no en el navegador donde se produce la "acción" para el visitante de tu web. busca ajax o jquery que es bueno para los principiantes